# React app deployed to github pages doesn't include repository name when determining the root

Tags: reactjs, routes, github-pages, vite, root

Created a react app using Vite that works fine locally. But when I deploy it to github pages, it doesn't include the repository name when routing.
This is the url of my small app:
https://tehcatsmiaw.github.io/imagerfe/
That should be the root of the project, but it doesn't work as it should. With a bit of investigating, the app considers just https://tehcatsmiaw.github.io/ as the root. that can be seen by clicking on the logo or on the "Create" button.
The app works fine if I just take out the repository name, but that is going to cause problems later on.

this is my app.jsx that does the routing:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import { logo } from "./assets";
import { Home, CreatePost } from "./pages";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <header className="w-full flex justify-between items-center bg-white sm:px-8 px-4 py-4 border-b border-b-[#e6ebf4]">
        <Link to="/">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-28 object-contain" />
        </Link>

        <Link
          to="/create-post"
          className="font-inter font-medium bg-[#6469ff] text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md"
        >
          Create
        </Link>
      </header>

      <main className="sm:p-8 px-4 py-8 w-full bg-[#f9fafe] min-h-[calc(100vh-73px)]">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/create-post" element={<CreatePost />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://tehcatsmiaw.github.io/imagerfe/",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

and the vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/imagerfe/",
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

Guessing the problem has to be in one of these 3 files.

I tried changing the homepage in the package.json, messed around with the Vite config file, but nothing seems to work. And being a beginner, I don't even know if my problem is code relate or something that needs to be changed in the way I deploy to github pages or some of the setting files.
For refference, this is the guide I used to deploy to gh pages:
and all the files for my frontend of my small app can be found here:
https://github.com/tehcatsmiaw/imagerfe